# Traveling Salesman problem solution for small graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, graph-traversal

So let's say i have a graph like this and salesman starts his journey at "A" [image]

How do i solve the TSP problem for this graph with pen and paper on exam?

Comment: The idea of computer science is that instead of doing things by hand, you devise an algorithm and let the computer do them for you. Ask your TA for tips, or tell your lecturer that this type of question is against the spirit of the area.

Comment: Use any algorithm which you train a lot. Note that there are only 24 solutions in total, so you can even quickly write down all of them. (I think this is unworthy of an exams, but well.)

Comment: @Raphael unless the point of the exercise is to introduce the 2-approximation for Euclidian TSP, as an introduction to approximation algorithms or to get some extra millage out of MST with this 'application'. Either way BE, DE and/or BD seem to be missing?

Comment: @Fasermaler If the task was "Apply algorithm A to this instance", it could work as an *exercise*. Apparently, the OP expects to be asked to provide an optimal tour, which is a trivial task on an instance this size.

Comment: @Raphael Agreed, I was going from my GT instructor who happened to be very clear that we're not supposed to be solving NP-hard problems on exams. If at any time we found ourselves trying to do so, we'd better check if we understood the question correctly. I guess not all instructors are this enlightened.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus OK. So we can interpret this question as, "Is there an algorithm that one can use to sovle small instances of TSP reasonably efficiently and for which one could track the necessary data structures using pencil and paper? Alternatively, given a guessed minimal tour, is there any way to prove that it is indeed minimal?"